# BeautifulSoup: Using value from html element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a question on how to use the extracted data from a webpage on BeautifulSoup4. Here is my code:

```
url = "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_0?me=A2L77EE7U53NWQ&fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A1267877011%2Cn%3A1267879011%2Cn%3A1294322011%2Cn%3A1297815011&bbn=1294322011&ie=UTF8&qid=1501968446"
page = requests.get(url)
resultsCol = SoupStrainer(id="resultsCol")
time.sleep(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser', parse_only=resultsCol)

sResultItem = soup.find_all("li", {"class": "s-result-item"})
for dataAsins in sResultItem:
    dataAsin = dataAsins['data-asin']
    print(dataAsin)
```

What I would like to do is to use the data-asin numbers separately from the rest. However, whenever I try to print `dataAsin[0:10]` it gives me all of the data-asins instead of just one. If I could have some help with this issue I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance for the feedback.

Comment: Also, what kind of datatype is the 'dataAsin' variable?

Comment: What are you getting in `dataAsins`?  Also, you can get the type of a variable with `type(dataAsin)`.  When I'm writing code I use a lot of `print('var', type(var), var)` statements.

Comment: `dataAsin` is a string, so `dataAsin[0:10]` gives you the first 10 characters.

Comment: This is the output of 'data-asins' : B002TZ4CRG
B00006I5O6
B00028ONIA
B00020S7XK
B0015YRMXI
B0033UPFT0
B00375MPA8
B0028QREZ8
B0007ZL6DS
B007KZQM9Q
B0026VWNGU
B001BBOZ08
B000067RHR

Comment: dataAsin[0:10] prints all of the numbers and dataAsin[0] prints 'B' eleven times

Comment: Use `soup.find` if you only need the 1st item.

Comment: I need all of them but I want to use them separately. I should've made that clear. I apologize

Comment: Ok, use `sResultItem[0]` then.

Comment: It's the data-asins values that I need. If I could put them into a list and call to each ten digit code separately through an index, that would be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to collect all the 'data-asin' attributes in a list. Then you can select any item you want.

```
dataAsins = [ li['data-asin'] for li in sResultItem ]
```